# Scrapy selector cannot return desired characters possibly due to Javascript

Tags: javascript, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape data from this Chinese webpage http://bxt.harbin.gov.cn/hrb_bzbxt/disshow.php?id=551950.

In Scrapy shell, I cannot get any text in any td elements. For example, `response.xpath("/html/body/center[2]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/text()").extract()` returns an empty list. The same thing is returned for other similar commands too. When I inspect the html more closely, I find this in the head element: "script language = "javascript". I'm not sure if this is the cause of the problem. Could anybody help me figure out? I searched Stackoverflow for related topics, but it's too complex for me to grasp. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can anybody help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem here is that you are using a full path to get to the information you want, this isn't necessary, so no need to follow `html` -> `body` -> `center`, etc.

You could just go directly to the `td` information you need, with something like:

```
response.xpath('//td/text()')
```

which will return a list of selectors (every text inside a `td` tag) to iterate with the information you need.